# Range of ordinal numbers

Tags: python

My disgusting list comprehension in the `return` statement is quite a headful.

```
"""Hopefully this function will save you the trip to oocalc/excel.

"""

def rangeth(start, stop=None, skip=1):
    """rangeth([start,] stop[, skip])

returns a list of strings as places in a list (1st, 2nd, etc)

>>> rangeth(4)
['0th', '1st', '2nd', '3rd']

    """

    if stop is None:
        stop, start = start, 0

    places = {'1':'st', '2':'nd', '3':'rd'}

    return ["{}{}".format(i, places.get(i[-1], 'th')) \
            if i[-2:] not in ['11', '12', '13'] else "{}{}".format(i, 'th') \
            for i in map(str, range(start, stop, skip))]
```

Also, can someone explain to me how `range` accepts it's parameters? I have my ugly little boilerplate here that I wish didn't exist. I can't find the source for range, as I gave up after thinking it's probably some header file in `include`.

Comment: Range - http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range. Which version of Python are you using? I'm a novice at python, but one thing I know is that `yield` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained) would allow using loops which would most likely make this code much more readable (but maybe not as efficient, I don't know).

Comment: This won't work `version <= 2.6` due to the `.format()` function. Also, your link to the doc, though appreciated, isn't what I was after. If you look at the calltip in IDLE for range, there are no default values given. My function posts `rangeth(start, stop=None...`, which I don't like.

Comment: Aha! [I found what I was looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644537/how-does-the-python-range-function-have-a-default-parameter-before-the-actual-on).

Comment: I think your new version fails for 121.

Comment: There is a module: `inflect` http://pypi.python.org/pypi/inflect/0.2.1 It has an ordinal-function which may be an alternate solution! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I'd suggest not duplicating the overloading logic of range. Instead:

```
def rangeth(*args):
    print range(*args)
```

Just take your arguments and pass them onto to range.

Secondly, I'd write a function that takes a single number and produces the "th"ified version.

```
def as_th(number):
    number = str(number)
    if number[-2:] in ['11','12','13]:
         return "{}{}".format(number, 'th')
    else:
         return "{}{}".format(number, places.get(number[-1], 'th'))
```

I think that makes it easier to follow.

Then have you rangeth function be:

```
def rangeth(*args):
    return map(as_th, range(*args))
```

Comment: I didn't like returning the `map` object. I just used `return [ nth(x) for x in range(*args) ]`. But, +1 for producing the stand-alone `nth(n)` function, which is nice.

Comment: Follow up: didn't realize that Python 3k returns [map objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303347/getting-a-map-to-return-a-list-in-python-3-1), which is why I wasn't getting a list back.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my 2cents as a two-liner:

```
mark=lambda p:'{0}{1}'.format(p,('th','st','nd','rd')[p] if p%10<4 and p/10 != 1 else 'th')
map(mark, xrange(30))
```

delievers:
['0th', '1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th', '5th', '6th', '7th', '8th', '9th', '10th', '11th', '12th', '13th', '14th', '15th', '16th', '17th', '18th', '19th', '20th', '21st', '22nd', '23rd', '24th', '25th', '26th', '27th', '28th', '29th']

Comment: Doesn't this miss the logic for numbers like "21st"

Comment: This is obviously a function that could be reused and would be relevant in many situations, so turning it into a lambda is unnecessary and kills readability.

Comment: A couple things...`p` can quickly climb out of the range of `('th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd')` tuple. I fixed it, and will post it in my updated solution (I liked the fact that you never converted to `str`. So, net +1).